# Display local pdf file in UIWebView in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am display local pdf file in UIWebView but it shows exception in path here is my code

```
     NSString*fileName=content_Source;
     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"pdf"];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [webView loadRequest:request]
```

Comment: what exception error..?

Comment: @NitinGohel this is the exception nating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first validate that string and the assign to URL like bellow..

```
   NSString *strURLPath = [self trimString: path];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strURLPath];
```

use my bellow method...

```
-(NSString*) trimString:(NSString *)theString {
    if (theString != [NSNull null])
        theString = [theString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    return theString;
}
```

Comment: same erros @ParasJoshi -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: First check what you get in content_Source variable??? NSLog(@"\n\n content_Source ==>> %@",content_Source);

Comment: if i am giving direct name then it is working     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rglucagon-pi" ofType:@"pdf"];

Comment: yes exactly i want to say you that and for that i toild you first chcek what u get in content_Source variable... check that...

Comment: here in your content_Source variable is nil and so you get this error first assign that name to this variable like this content_Source = @"rglucagon-pi"; and then retain it like [content_Source retain]; and then assign it to the file name and it will worked.. :)

Comment: @ParasJoshi: Please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874538/failed-to-download-and-open-a-pdf-file-with-error-failed-to-find-pdf-header-in-i

Answer (score 6):

You must be using the file name extension while setting the file name. So make sure the extension will not be used in file name if it's setting along with Type (like ofType:@"pdf").

Here's my code:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
NSString*fileName= @"About_Downloads";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO]];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

There's a better way to show PDFs:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *dc = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO]];
dc.delegate = self; 
[dc presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

Make sure use the delegate along with that code to work it properly.

```
(UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller{
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine with the given code problem was that in my file Name  i was giving also the  type like ali.pdf they type pdf so it get exception it worked fine now when i use filename like following

```
 NSString*fileName=@"ali";
```

Instead of

```
    NSString*fileName=@"ali.pdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = rect.size;
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```